# React Context returning Undefined

Tags: reactjs

This is the first time context has ever given me problems. I tried following examples and tutorials but none of them worked. Can anyone offer any suggestions to what I'm doing wrong, as my code and other people's context code hasn't worked thus far.

context.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { createContext } from 'react'

export const DataContext = createContext();

class DataContextProvider extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
           users:[],
           messages:[]
        }
    
    }
    addUser = (user) => {
        this.setState({
            users:[...this.state.users,user]
        })
    }
    addMessage = (message) => {
        this.setState({
            messages:[...this.state.messages,message]
        })
    }

    render() {
        const {addUser,addMessage} = this;  
        return (

           <DataContext.Provider value={{
               ...this.state,
                addUser,
                addMessage
              
           }}>
         
               {this.props.children}
           </DataContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default DataContextProvider;
```

app.js

```
import DataContextProvider from './Components/context';
function App() {
  return (
   
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
       <DataContextProvider>
        <div className="App">
          <Header />
          <Main />
        </div>
      </DataContextProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
 
  );
}
```

Content.js

```
const data = useContext(DataContextProvider);
console.log(data) // returns undefined
```

Comment: Shouldn't you `useContext(DataContext)`? The provider is the wrapper component. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: That doesn't work either , still returns undefined

Comment: Is Content.js creating a component that is nested within the provider? The source provided above doesn't appear to show that.

Comment: props.children is nested between <DataContext.Provider> </DataContext.Provider>.